# Mongoose - Find documents where array doesn't have any matches

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the schema for my collection:

```
{
    _id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    translations: [{
        language: String,
        translation: String
    }]
}
```

If I have an array of languages, `["spanish", "french"]`, how can I find all the documents where `Collection.translations` doesn't have an object for at least one of the languages in the array?

For example, this should be selected:

```
{
    _id: "hello",
    translations: [{
        language: "not spanish",
        translation: "not hola"
    }]
}
```

But not these:

```
{
    _id: "hello",
    translations: [{
        language: "spanish",
        translation: "hola"
    }]
}
//and
{
    _id: "hello",
    translations: [{
        language: "spanish",
        translation: "hola"
    }, {
        language: "french",
        translation: "bonjour"
    }, {
        language: "not spanish",
        translation: "not hola"
    }]
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
Model.findOne({
    translations: { $elemMatch: { language: ??? } }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator, try:

```
Model.findOne({
   'translations.language': { $nin: [ "spanish", "french" ] }
});
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed. Also, I didn't know you could use dot notation with objects in arrays. Thank you!